# how to print proper error message

Tags: shell, scripting

I have following small shell script.

```
value='testdir/imp'
`mkdir -m 755 $value`
echo $
```

the out put is

```
$ ./dir.sh 
mkdir: Failed to make directory "testdir/imp"; Permission denied
2
```

Here i want to print this error message to a text file 
How i can do this

Comment: You probably don't want backticks around your `mkdir` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case

```
$ ./dir.sh 2 > log.file
```

should put you error message in the file log.file

Answer (score 1):

mkdir prints error messages to stderr. You can also redirect the output from stderr to a file. Knowing these 2 things you can do this:

```
mkdir /etc/test 2>somefile
```

And then the output from mkdir will be in a somefile.

The syntax `2>somefile` redirects stderr to a file called `somefile`.